# TYPO3 9.5 Install extension error (upload_max_filesize and post_max_size)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I'm actually trying to install [phpmyadmin extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/phpmyadmin) to my brand new 9.5 Typo3 installation.
However, when I try to upload the extension file (both .zip and .tx3) I get the error message:

> Creating temporary file failed. Check your upload_max_filesize and post_max_size_limits

When I checkout phpInfo on typo3 I have:

```
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
memory_limit = 128M
```

As I mentioned earlier I'm on version 9.5 of Typo3, so "maxFileSize" isn't available.

Comment: That ZIP file is not even _ten_ MB in size, so I don’t see how this should have anything to do with those limits. Guess that error message might be somewhat misleading, can you check what the actual PHP error log has to say? I’d guess this has either something to do with file system permissions in some place, or the PHP configuration is otherwise “off” regarding file uploads maybe (upload temp dir does not exist, or can’t be written to.)

Comment: Actually on php log I got nothing special, on typo3 I find the exact same error message. I also thought it's a permission issue so made sure to chmod it but nothing changed :(